# unable to parse a node from xml string with dom4j

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom4j

I'm parsing a xml string with dom4j and I'm using xpath to select some element from it, the code is :

```
    String test = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><epp xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0\"><response><result code=\"1000\"><msg lang=\"en-US\">Command completed successfully</msg></result><trID><clTRID>87285586-99412370</clTRID><svTRID>52639BB8-1-ARNES</svTRID></trID></response></epp>";
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    reader.setIncludeExternalDTDDeclarations(false);
    reader.setIncludeInternalDTDDeclarations(false);
    reader.setValidation(false);
    Document xmlDoc;
    try {
        xmlDoc = reader.read(new StringReader(test));
        xmlDoc.getRootElement();
        Node nodeStatus = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//epp/response/result");

        System.out.print(nodeStatus.getText());
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I always get null for the nodeStatus variable. I actualy nead to read the code from the result noad from the xml

```
<result code="1000">
```

This is the XML that I am reading from the `String test`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
    <response>
        <result code="1000">
            <msg lang="en-US">Command completed successfully</msg>
        </result>
        <trID>
            <clTRID>87285586-99412370</clTRID>
            <svTRID>52639BB8-1-ARNES</svTRID>
        </trID>
    </response>
</epp>
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML has a namespace. DOM4J returns null because it won't find your nodes.

To make it work, you first have to register the namespaces you are using. You will need a prefix. Any one. And you will have to use that prefix in your XPath.

You could use `tns` for "target namespace". Then you have to create a `xpath` object with it like this:

```
XPath xpath = new DefaultXPath("/tns:epp/tns:response/tns:result");
```

To register the namespaces you will need to create a `Map`, add the namespace with the prefix you used in the xpath expression, and pass it to the `setNamespaceURIs()` method.

```
namespaces.put("tns", "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0");
xpath.setNamespaceURIs(namespaces);
```

Now you can call `selectSingleNode`, but you will call it on your XPath object passing the document as the argument:

```
Node nodeStatus = xpath.selectSingleNode(xmlDoc);
```

From there you can extract the data you need. `getText()` won't give you the data you want. If you want the contents of the result node as XML, you can use:

```
nodeStatus.asXML()
```

**Edit**: to retrieve just the code, change your XPath to:

```
/tns:epp/tns:response/tns:result/@code
```

And retrieve the result with

```
nodeStatus.getText();
```

I replaced the double slash `//` (which means descendant-or-self) with `/` since the expression contains the full path and `/` is more efficient. But if you only have one `result` node in your whole file, you can use:

```
//result/@code
```

to extract the data. It will match all descendants. If there is more than one `result`, it will return a node-set.

Comment: tnx for the info, i'm a little blurry with those namespace terms, havent worked with xml-s in that way till now. What about the @ in xpath I have read somewhere that with @ is possible to red the parameter from some xml noad, for example //epp/response/result/@code?

Comment: Yes. If you just want the code string add `/@code` to the end of your XPath expression. Now you can retrieve the text using `getText()`.

Comment: Ok if a add a namespace it works, but the parsed result is strange in the asXML() method for /tns:epp/tns:response/tns:result i get the namespace added in result node for example this <result xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" code="1000"><msg lang="en-US">Command completed successfully</msg></result>, in the original xml there is no namespace in the result node, it is added during parsing

Comment: The namespace actually _is_ part of the original document, since it's declared in the root element and inherited by all child nodes. The valid result requires the namespace. I am not sure about how you can remove the namespace in Dom4J. There probably is a `remove()` method where you can remove a namespace. You can also extract the individual nodes you need (//result/@code, //result/msg) and deliver the response in a new XML adding it to a new `<result>` node.

Comment: But if all you need is the code, use `getText()` with xpath as `//result/@code` and you get just the string, without any other namespace information.